# Where does LOW-9 comes from?

Tags: symbols, unicode

In Polish typography a quotation is put in between `„` (U+201e) and right quotation mark `”` (U+201d). The opening symbol is called "double low-9 quotation mark" in the Unicode.

Where does it come from? I couldn't imagine what "low-9" specifically refers to.

Comment: While the question is interesting, it has nothing to do with TeX and friends. Why the Unicode Consortium decided for such a name is, for me, a mystery. Not the only one, actually, but they had to chose some unique name.

Comment: I didn't find any other suitable StackExchange for this question... As the accepted answer suggests it has something to do with the "look" of the character, hence very much related to the fontface used -- so maybe not so off-topic yet?

Comment: @pwes Your question is off-topic. I just decided to answer it anyways because I knew the answer, and I believe it can be migrated to either [graphicdesign.SE] (since it's partly a typography question) or [SU] (since it's about unicode). I've already contacted the mods, let's see if it gets migrated or not ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's
- `9` as `99` as `”`
- `6` as `66` as `“`

Well, the font here isn't quite showing it, on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark), better ones can be found:

[image]

Comment: Well, looks like my imagination is really lacking... ;) Thanks!